# setMinDate for CalendarView

Tags: android, calendarview

I'm trying to set the minimum date programmatically for a CalendarView widget like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.dialog_date_select);
CalendarView calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
calendar.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

But for some reason I'm getting the following error

```
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
activity ComponentInfo{com.patientsnow/com.patientsnow.activity.DateSelectActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
Method)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at 
com.patientsnow.activity.DateSelectActivity.onCreate(DateSelectActivity.java:36)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-05 12:50:14.054: E/AndroidRuntime(798):  ... 11 more
```

Line 36 of DateSelectActivity is where I try to setMinDate. Why is this code not setting the minimum date? As a note if I try to set the minimum date and maximum date in the XML, then it works.

Comment: make sure you are calling `setContentView` before accessing `calendarView1`

Comment: I am doing that. I edited the question.

Comment: Evidently, `findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);` returns `null`. That's either because `R.id.calendarView1` is *not* the id for the `CalenderView` present the in the layout file, or you're trying to inflate from the wrong view hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you MH that was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Time myTimeMin = new Time();
    myTimeMin.set(19, 11-1, 2014);
    myCalendarView.setDate(myTimeMin.toMillis(true));
    myCalendarView.setMinDate(myCalendarView.getDate());

    Time myTimeMax = new Time();
    //myTimeMax.set(10, 12-1, 2014);
    myTimeMax.setToNow();
    myCalendarView.setDate(myTimeMax.toMillis(true));
    myCalendarView.setMaxDate(myCalendarView.getDate());
```